# "ruby.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command" in windows 7

Tags: ruby, windows-7, heroku

My os is windows 7 and I was about to connect my localhost MySQL database with the Heroku shared database, in one point of time, I got the error libmysql.dll file missing, so I searched and downloaded the dll file and saved it in ruby/bin directory. Again when I was about to connect, this time it shows the error ruby.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command this is how the error looks.

Sending schema

```
'"ruby.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,TA:  --:--:--
operable program or batch file.
'"ruby.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,TA:  00:00:07
operable program or batch file.
'"ruby.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,TA:  00:00:04
operable program or batch file.
'"ruby.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,TA:  00:00:02
operable program or batch file.
'"ruby.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,TA:  00:00:01
operable program or batch file.
```

Schema:        100% 
    |==========================================| Time: 00:00:06
    '"ruby.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.

```
C:/Program Files/Heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/taps-0.3.23/lib/vendor/okj
son.rb:82:in `valparse': unexpected nil (OkJson::ParserError)
    from C:/Program Files/Heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/taps-0.3.23/l
ib/vendor/okjson.rb:64:in `textparse'
from C:/Program Files/Heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/taps-0.3.23/l
ib/vendor/okjson.rb:43:in `decode'
from C:/Program Files/Heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/taps-0.3.23/l
ib/taps/operation.rb:419:in `push_indexes'
from C:/Program Files/Heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/taps-0.3.23/l
ib/taps/operation.rb:408:in `block in run'
from C:/Program Files/Heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/taps-0.3.23/l
ib/taps/operation.rb:203:in `call'
from C:/Program Files/Heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/taps-0.3.23/l
ib/taps/operation.rb:203:in `catch_errors'
from C:/Program Files/Heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/taps-0.3.23/l
ib/taps/operation.rb:405:in `run'
from C:/Program Files/Heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/taps-0.3.23/l
ib/taps/cli.rb:171:in `clientxfer'
from C:/Users/JOE ARPUTHAN/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/db.rb:194:i
n `taps_client'
from C:/Users/JOE ARPUTHAN/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/db.rb:35:in
 `push'
from C:/Users/JOE ARPUTHAN/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:129:in `
run'
from C:/Program Files/Heroku/heroku:27:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Linux answer: ruby is not in your `$PATH`. I think it's `%PATH%` in Windows.

Comment: Make sure to select Boris' answer as correct if it worked for you, and maybe do so for your other questions too.

Comment: I wish I could double plus this! :D

Answer (score 50):

You don't have the `ruby.exe`'s path in your PATH variable.

In windows 7 you can set it by `Start menu` -> right click `My computer` -> last option on the left (I think it was `advanced settings`) -> Environment variables -> in `system variables` sub menu find `Path` double click it and add ; then the path to the bin folder of your ruby installation. This should fix it (you will need to restart all command prompts you have launched).

Comment: that worked for me,thanks a Ton tazz and boris  [ set path=%path%;"c:\Program Files\Heroku\ruby\bin"] putting this in the command prompt solved it,thanks again

Comment: @TheFrost For me launching a new terminal is sufficient no need to reboot the whole system

Comment: @BorisStrandjev - This did not work for me. Can you please help me at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212246/java-programmer-need-help-to-install-and-setup-ruby . Thanks in advance.

Comment: It didn't work at start for me - remember to RESTART your computer - after it everything worked fine.

Comment: @Morfidon: you should not need to restart the entire machine - starting a new terminal should be sufficient (if you interact with Ruby from `cmd` terminal).

Comment: So awesome to hear an answer that doesn't include an elitist "Throw your Windows computer away and use Linux" answer from the snobby open source crowd.