# Why is 'ruby' not recognized as an internal or external command?

Tags: ruby, railsinstaller, railsinstaller-windows

Path in user variable is the default path from the installation:

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin
```

Path in system variable is directed to:

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin
```

When I open the Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails, the command prompt says "'ruby' is not recognized as an internal or external command" immediately without any input.

The command prompt worked before. After I re-installed it using various methods due to unsuccessful setup, it got like this.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 22):

Please restart cmd before running ruby command.

Comment: Why does restarting something always fix it  thank you Ilyas

Comment: Just a note - Restart is need also in VS Code Terminal!

Answer (score 3):

In Windows PC:
To add bin path of your installed ruby to PATH environmental variable
 1. right click on "My Computer" -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environmental Variables -> Select "Path" ->Edit
Example path shown below:
D:\Ruby22\bin;
 2. Restart cmd after changes

Refer below image:
[Ruby Path setting in Windows 7 and other windows OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ushfq.png)

Answer (score 2):

1. Ensure you have the correct x32 or x64 bit version of Ruby
   installed.
2. Ensure you have the PATH environment variable setup, this should be
   done automatically if selected upon install.
3. Lastly ensure you restart your command prompt.

[image: Ruby installer]

Answer (score 1):

So,
`C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3.\bin` is the place where your ruby.exe is saved?
If that's correct, you should be able to access the ruby commands via the Command Prompt.

When you try: `REG QUERY "HKCU\Environment"` in the console, is there an output like?:

```
PATH REG_EXPAND_SZ C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3.\bin
```

Comment: Yes the ruby.exe is saved in 'C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3.\bin'. I'm following instruction from http://railsinstaller.org/ and I don't have a console yet. I've tried to install different version of ruby, but all of them behave the problem stated above. I'm suspecting it's command prompt's problem, since there is nothing wrong with the path. In addition, when I try to open the ruby.exe directly, it just pop up an empty command window.

Comment: At the end of the installation, a window prompts up says Ruby.exe is not executable.

Comment: I am receiving the same error, except that I have full access to IRB.  I also tried  'set path=%path%;"c:\Program Files\Heroku\ruby\bin”'

from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852259/ruby-exe-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-windows-7